# Conjugation Quandles and... "Quandle-Groups"? From quandles to Groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, knot-theory

A quandle $(Q,*,/ )$ is a idempotent right-distributive and right invertible structure.

> 1) $a*a=a$
>
> 2) $(a*b)*c=(a*c)*(b*c)$
>
> 3) $(a*b) /b=(a/b)*b=a$

If we have a group $(G, \cdot, e,^{-1})$ and $*$ is the cojugation operation on $G$

$$a*b:=bab^{-1}$$

and

$$a/b:=a*b^{-1}$$

then $(G,*,/)$ is denoted with $Conj(G)$ and is a quandle because it satisfies the quandles axioms

> 1) $a*a=a=aaa^{-1}$
>
> 2) $(a*b)*c=(a*c)*(b*c)$

because $c(bab^{-1})c^{-1}=(cbc^{-1})cac^{-1}(cb^{-1}c^{-1})=cbab^{-1}c^{-1}$

> 3) $(a*b) *b^{-1}=(a*b^{-1})*b=a$

because $b^{-1}(bab^{-1})b=b(b^{-1}ab)b^{-1}=a$

I read that we have too that a group homomorphism between two groups $G$ and $G'$ is a quandle homomorphism between theire cojugation quandles $Conj(G)$ and $Conj(G')$ and that makes $Conj$ a functor betwen the category of Groups and the category of quandles...

---

I wanted to know more about this functor $Conj$ that "maps" Groups to Quandles and since I'm not expert of category theory I apologize if I use a wrong terminology

> $Q1a$ - I learnt that not every Quandle is a conjugation Quandle or in
>   other words $conj$ is not ""surjective"" on the "set" of all quandles
>   (that is not a set but a class i think) so how can I prove that a
>   Quandle is a Conjugation Quandle too?
>
> $Q1b$ -Wich extra "axioms" must hold in a Quandle that is a
>   Conjugation Quandle?

This has something to do with the inverse construction of $Conj$ so my next question is

> $Q2$ - There is a way to define a group operation starting with a
>   quandle operation? Like an inverse $Conj$ construction that build a "Quandle-Group" $Conj^{-1}(Q)$ from a conjugation quandle $Q$.
>
> $Q3$ Is this process unique?

With unique I mean is is possible to have two different groups $G=(G,\cdot,\phi)$ and $G'=(G,\circ,\varphi)$ and $$Conj (G)= Conj(G')$$

this should mean that is possible to have

$$b\cdot a\cdot \phi(b)=b \circ a \circ \varphi(b)$$

where $\phi(b)$and $\varphi(b)$ are the inverse functions and

$$a \cdot b \neq a \circ b$$

> $Q4$ My last question is if possible to generalize the conjugation
>   operation of groups for monoids and semigruops in a way that these
>   "Monoid-conjugations" and "Semigroup-conjugations" are quandles. If is possible I would like to read more about.

---

I've asked this question on MathOverflow here:[From quandles to groups](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/162835/conjugation-quandles-and-quandle-groups-from-quandles-to-groups)

Comment: The conjugation quandle of an abelian group is a so-called trivial quandle (i.e., x*y = x, identically), so any two abelian groups of the same order give rise to isomorphic conjugation quandles.

Comment: I don't know if there is a complete characterisation of conjugation quandles, but conjugation quandles are *crossed sets*.  A crossed set is a quandle that satisfies the additional condition that, for any two elements $a$ and $b$, one has $a*b = a$ if, and only if, $b*a = b$.  There is a quandle of order $3$ that is not a crossed set. (Of course, it is not faithful.) However, a crossed set need not be a conjugation quandle.  There are $4$ crossed sets of order $4$ (up to isomorphism), but only one conjugation quandle.

Comment: Yea @James that happens with element that commute like the powers of $a$. So we should have that if in a quandle your statement holds then $a$ should be(!?) a group power of $b$ (or viceversa) for a unknown group operation...but only if that quandle is a conjugation-Q..right?

Comment: I don't think so (if I understand your point correctly).  You could have two elements of a group that commute, but neither is a power of the other.

Comment: yes you're right... then just change the "should be" with a "could be". I'm very curious about this problem..if I dont get an answer could be ok to ask this on MO?

Comment: I'd also be very interested if there is a known way to characterise a conjugation quandle.  I don't recall ever having seen one.

Comment: If you do post over on MO, be sure to cross-link the questions.

Comment: @James question is cross-linked on MO.

Comment: Rather than an inverse functor, perhaps you should look for a *left adjoint* to $Conj$, say $F:  Quand \to Grp$ such that $\operatorname{Hom}_{Grp} \left( F(Q), G \right) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_{Quand} \left( Q, Conj(G) \right)$ for any quandle $Q$ and any group $G$.